# How do I (gracefully) terminate a gSOAP server?

Tags: c++, qt, web-services, gsoap

I have gSOAP server generated from a WSDL file + a Qt GUI. The generated code works perfectly fine, except one point that causes my process to stay alive after GUI exits. (I'm deploying on Windows, so I have no signaling)

I need my GUI to stay alive (naturally) so I moved server-proxy object to a `QObject`-based class that the latter is moved to another `QThread`, and the I fire it up by an external signal. The server now runs on event-loop of its parent QObject and works fine.

The only problem is that I have no clue how to terminate server on exit. I tried tweaking generated code for server (is that really a good idea by the way?)

```
int MySweetService::run(int port)
{   if (!soap_valid_socket(this->soap->master) && !soap_valid_socket(this->bind(NULL, port, 100)))
        return this->soap->error;
    for (;;) // =====> Maybe here I can put my while(module_is_running_atomic_bool) ?
    {   if (!soap_valid_socket(this->accept()))
        {   if (this->soap->errnum == 0) // timeout?
                this->soap->error = SOAP_OK;
            break;
        }
        if (this->serve())
            break;
        this->destroy();
    }
    return this->soap->error;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling soap_done(&soap) from another thread terminates blocking call to accept() and next your "serving" thread. It works for me on Windows but I doesn't on Linux - it looks like gsoap has some multitasking issue. You also need some boolean flag to let "serving" thread know that you shut it down and it's not just error in gsope.